# Metasploit Directory Doesn't Run Executables Without ./

Tags: shell, osx, path, metasploit

I have Metasploit installed on OSX in `/usr/local/share/msf`

Metasploit's executables can't be run outside it's directory thus would give a *command not found* error.

```
msfbinscan
msfconsole
msfd
msfelfscan
msfmachscan
msfpescan
msfrop
msfrpc 
msfrpcd
msfupdate
msfvenom
```

For me, only `msfconsole` runs without having a `./` prefix but the rest executes but gives no output unless I add `./msfupdate` for example.

How would I run `msf*` files with the prefix as if I was running a built in command? I've tried symlinking the directory as a $MSF enviroment to `/usr/local/bin` but that never worked and it's also a known issue.

For example:

`$: ./msfvenom` works but `$: msfvenom` runs but doesn't output anything thus doesn't do anything.

All my `msf*` files are **-rwxr-xr-x**

Is there some sort of way to fix this or similar?

Answer (score 0):

To run a command by typing its name, the command must be in one of the directories listed in the [`PATH` environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). Being in the current directory is not good enough. Being in a subdirectory of a directory in PATH is not good enough.

So edit `/etc/profile` to add the full path to the directory where the Metasploit binaries are. On OSX, the change will take effect in new terminals that you open.

Answer (score 0):

After messing around i've finally got them working. One simple command was all it took:

**sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/msf/msf* /usr/local/sbin**